# Time Picker widget - "id cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android, android-widget, datetimepicker

I'm getting the error for the following lines:

```
mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
mPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime);
```

Although at this stage I'm merely copy-pasting stuff from the Tutorial, just to get a feel for it.. So where am I going wrong guys?

This is the .java file as a whole:

```
package com.example.hellotimepicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloTimePicker extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextView mTimeDisplay;
    private Button mPickTime;

    private int mHour;
    private int mMinute;

    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // capture our View elements
        mTimeDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
        mPickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime);

        // add a click listener to the button
        mPickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        // get the current time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // display the current date
        updateDisplay();

    }

 // updates the time we display in the TextView
    private void updateDisplay() {
        mTimeDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    .append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
                    .append(pad(mMinute)));
    }

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you missed to copy the layout (xml code) from the tutorial

Comment: Or forgot to add the time display field. Check for the timeDisplay view in the res/layout/main.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share my experience with the original tutorial version because this might be useful. Earlier I used:

```
import android.R;
```

But the `main` cannot be resolved at the line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

So I changed the `"import android.R;"` to:

```
import com.example.hellodatepicker.R; //to match with the package name
```

and found out it is running fine.